# Photoshop export for web and devices comes out pixelated.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

When I export for web and devices in photoshop CS5 it comes out pixelated. What setting should I change?

I have a picture of my export settings at http://www.brandonsdesigngroup.com/photoshop.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the colors are limited?
You're exporting it as a GIF, which is limited to 256 colors. You're using a lot of images, so you'll have more than 256 colors. I suggest exporting as a PNG instead, this should help you hold on to the quality.

Comment: what type of png 24 or 8

Comment: png-8 means it can hold 8 bits of color (or 256). png-24 means it can cold 24 bits (or 16 million colors).

Comment: so i want 24 bits

Comment: That is correct. Try it out and see how it comes out :]

Comment: ok the images are fine now but some of the text is pixelated look at the image below I'm exporting at a png 24 http://www.brandonsdesigngroup.com/fa_website/portfolio/hampton/images/hampton_04.png

Comment: @Brandon -- And you're sure it doesn't look like that BEFORE saving and it only looks like that after you save as PNG-24? Are you sure? Because I I just tried it myself it looks fine after being saved.

Comment: i realized i didn't anti-alias the text